# Is the ico editor gone with vs2015 update 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS2015 (14.0.24720) update 1.

If I try to edit an ico file in VS2015 it always opens paint. How can find the old included ico Editor from Visual Studion?

**EDIT**:
help/info list

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installierte Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-90000-70216-AA711
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® und Unified Modeling Language™ sind Marken oder eingetragene Marken der Object Management Group, Inc. in den Vereinigten Staaten und anderen Ländern.

Visual Basic 2015   00322-90000-70216-AA711
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-90000-70216-AA711
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-90000-70216-AA711
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Visual F# 2015   00322-90000-70216-AA711
Microsoft Visual F# 2015

Allgemeine Azure-Tools   1.5
Bietet allgemeine Dienste für die Verwendung durch Azure Mobile Services und Microsoft Azure-Tools.

Application Insights Tools für Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools für Visual Studio

ASP.NET und Webtools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
ASP.NET und Webtools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Crystal Reports für .NET Framework   
Crystal Reports für .NET Framework


JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2016 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet-Paket-Manager   3.3.0
NuGet-Paket-Manager in Visual Studio. Weitere Informationen zu NuGet finden Sie unter "http://docs.nuget.org/".

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio-Erweiterung zur Visualisierung aggregierter Zusammenfassungen vom PreEmptive Analytics-Produkt.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.7.4.0
TypeScript für Microsoft Visual Studio
```

Comment: Alive and well on my machine.  What might be wrong with yours is forever hard to guess from such a short question, you need a site where psychics give free advice.  Spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: its not just my machine:( we got a team of 4 here and the 2 with the update 1 all missing the icon editor now.

Comment: Err, try opening the ICO file *in Visual Studio*, rather than from Explorer. Alternatively, right-click from Explorer and "Open With" Visual Studio. Sounds to me like you've just got your file associations messed up.

Comment: if i do this: VS2015 opened and then the ico open in paint. it seems that the Image Editor form vs2015  is broken or something

Comment: Have you tried running an experimental instance of VS, and check if the same happens there as well? It seems that the default external tool is being automatically picked up somehow. Maybe some extension added this feature.

Comment: Very unlikely the case... Anyway, how do you notice that it is gone? I mean, if the option for Image Editor is gone? Or it is there but you can't use it for ICO editing?

Comment: If you find a fix for this please post the answer.  I'm in the same boat :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling VS 2015 to get the image editor back, but it's possible I didn't have to: Looking at it now that it is working properly, by right-clicking the icon in the project explorer and selecting "Open With," I can see that the association in Visual Studio is with a tool called "Resource Editor."  I honestly don't know if that option was available before the reinstall - I was looking for things that began with words like "Image," not "Resource" anything.  Perhaps before reinstalling, you can right-click the icon in Visual Studio, select "Open With" and see if "Resource Editor" is an option.

Assuming that Resource Editor is not available or does not work, I would try the reinstall.  When I did it, I had to completely uninstall and reinstall, just trying a Repair install did not fix the problem.

One thing I did slightly differently on the reinstall - the first time I installed it was from an ISO image that I think only had update 1 on it, the second time I installed I downloaded a fresh copy of the .ISO that had update 2 on it.  Maybe that made a difference.

Comment: I suspect this is a lurking, intermittent bug in the Visual Studio setup because I am getting exactly the same issue today with VS2017 RC. Double-click the .ico in Solution Explorer and it fires up Paint. Look in the Open With list, Paint is there but Resource Editor is not. In my case, if I then open the solution in VS2015, Resource Editor does now feature and does get launched by default. I suspect if I reinstalled VS2017 RC it might start to appear there too.

Comment: It's not the setup that is buggy: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752106/visual-studio-2015-icon-editor
Modifying my installation with the "other languages" (c++,F#,...) pack was successful for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to open the icons *directly from your windows explorer*. In that way the application which is linked to the file type (.ico extension) will be launched - which is paint in your case.

Either change that link to point to Visual Studio or use the following way described in the documentation:

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccy67aya.aspx) the editor still exists and is rather easy to find/use.

> 1. From the **File** menu, click **Open**.
> 2. In the **Files of Type** box, click **All Files**.
> 3. Locate and open the image you want to edit.

However according to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx),...

> Using the Image Editor, you can view 32-bit images, but you cannot edit them.

Comment: if i do the 1-2-3 steps then also paint is opened on my machine with update 1, not on the machines without update 1.

Comment: That's completly weird because I have the same version installed as you (including Update 1) and it works perfectly for me...

Comment: always Paint 4 me:
From VStudio 2015 14.0.25123.00 Updt 2, Win10 10.0.10240
1.double click icon,opens with Paint
2.Project,Add New Item,Icon File: Paint
3.Right click .ico file,Open With,"Add...", "...Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" opens a new instance of VStudio,then Paint
4.On File Explorer,double click .ico,opens vstudio then Paint
5.File Explorer,right click,"Open With",VStudio Selector,opens vstudio,then Paint
6.Right click,"Open With","choose another app","always use...", "more apps","look for another app","...devenv.exe","Open",no such luck