# Visual Studio 2015 Icon Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2015, icons, image-editing

I started using Visual Studio 2015 since a couple of months and just noticed that the Icon Editor is missing!!!
In previous versions' of Visual Studio I always used the Image Editor for editing icons, but in 2015 I can't find it and, if I double click on an icon file it opens the Paint.

Maybe I forgot something on the installation or did Microsoft remove it from Visual Studio?

Comment: It is still there.  You are only the 2nd person complaining about this at SO, nobody yet has provided decent troubleshooting info.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have any concrete *reason* to believe it's still there?

Comment: Of course, it works on my machine.

Comment: @Formentz I ran the installer with the "Repair" option and I've got it now after a restart. Worth a shot anyhow.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I tried to repair the installation but it didn't work, thanks for the advice, anyway ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you install C++? I had the same problem, but was resolved after installing

Comment: @Fatcat: thanks man!! I installed all the optional programming languages (C++, F# and Python tools) and the icon editor magically appeared!

Comment: 3Gb of extra install, just for an icon editor?! Sigh

Comment: Modifying my installation with c++,... was enough! Thanks!

Comment: @freefaller To be more accurate, it is only needed to install Common tools for Visual C++ 2015, that is not 3Gb

Comment: Yup, installing Common tools for Visual C++ 2015 solved the issue- but it was ~2GB install

Comment: For ages I'd wondered why VS doesn't have an icon editor.  So it has one but it's hidden away in the optional C++ tools subpackage?  It's puzzling that MS decided if you're writing a GUI app in C# or VB then you're not going to want to give your app a meaningful icon.